Is it possible for an Azure Pipeline template to run in the same project it's in even when called in a different one?
I have an Azure Pipeline template that uses group variables and a specific agent pool, the repo where the template is, has access to both group variables and the agent pool but I when try to call this template from another project I get this error message: (Authorize resources doesn't do anything)
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Stage snapshot: Variable group creds could not be found. The variable group does not exist or has not been authorized for use. Could not find a pool with name agents_. The pool does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."

error message
Is there a way to make the template run like it's in its original repo, not from the project it's being called from?
When I tried calling the template from another repo in the same project, all I had to do was click on the 'Authorize Resources' button and all was good, but I also tried running it from another project in the same organization and a project in another organization but got the error.
This is how I call my template:
   resources:
      repositories:
        - repository: '<Repo Name>'
          name: <Project Name>/<Repo Name>
          type: git
          ref: <Branch Name>
    
   stages:
      - template: <Pipeline file.yml>@<Repo Name>
        parameters:
          Action: Delete
          HostIPs: <IPs>
          SnapshotName: <Name>
 


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre] on what code is required.

It's not supported to share variable group in pipeline from different project, you can only share in same project. It's a known limitation and a feature request ticket raised before.

As a workaround, you could create a same named variable group in the new project, with same variable and value defined. It will pass the validation. Or you can add these shared variables to Azure Key Vault, and download them in template by Azure Key Vault task, instead of variable group.
It's possible to share agent pool in different project pipeline, simply add your self-hosted pool to the project from project settings-> pipelines -> Agent pool.

